# Error trying to make POST request with Alamofire 4 and OAuth2 - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, post, http-headers, alamofire

I am integrating Reddit's API into my iOS application, however my POST request is not working, and I am using the Application Only OAuth method as seen [here](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#application-only-oauth). I am doing everything in my `AppDelegate` class. I am using Alamofire to perform requests.

```
open func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme == "APP_SCHEME" {
        let queryParams = url.query?.components(separatedBy: "&")
        var codeParam = (queryParams! as NSArray).filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH %@", "code="))
        let codeQuery = codeParam[0] as? String
        if let code = codeQuery?.replacingOccurrences(of: "code=", with: "") {
            print("My code is \(code)")

            guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token") else { return false }
            let params: Parameters = [
                "grant_type" : "https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client",
                "device_id" : "\(UUID().uuidString)"]

            let username = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
            let password = ""
            let loginString = String(format: "%@%@", username, password)
            let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
            let base64EncodedString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

            let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64EncodedString)"]

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post , parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
                print(response)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Whenever I run my application, log in to authorize through Reddit, and redirect to my application, my console prints out

```
   CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = reddit;
    srvr = "www.reddit.com";
    sync = syna;
}
SUCCESS: {
    error = 401;
    message = Unauthorized;
}
```

I've looked up the CredStore query error and a lot of other people are having it, I think it is an Alamofire issue with request handling. I have allowed Arbritary Loads in my `Info.plist`. As you can see I also get a 401 error, it must be my header but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: forgot a colon in my base64 encoding...

Comment: Where did you add the colon? Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238779/ios-oauth-signature-fails-with-invalid-signature-error